# Why check pockets on Shabbos?

Tags: shabbat, mistakes, lomdus, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot, maseches-shabbos

It says in Shabbos (12a) that one should always check his pockets on Friday so he won't accidentally carry on Shabbos.

I don't understand the purpose of this checking. Even if one *did* carry unintentionally, he would have been a Misasek which is Pattur (and possibly Muttar). According to Rava, who says that we don't make a Gezeira LeGezeira (11b), why check one's pockets?

Comment: Answer is probably connected to other instances, e.g. a tailor must not go out on friday afternoon with a needle in his clothes. Since it is usual to do so during the week, he might forget to remove it before shabbat and end up carrying it on shabbat. So too with pockets, since it is standard to always have things in pockets, it is very likely you will accidentally leave stuff in your pocket unless you make it a habit of checking before shabbat.

Answer (score 4):

On your way, you may suddenly realize that you have something in your pocket. At that point, it would certainly be assur to continue to carry it. Checking your pockets prevents you from being in this situation so it is not a gezeira legezeira.

Comment: then you can throw it out. Seems more like practical advice than hilchasa rabbasa leshabbasa

Comment: @ShmuelBrin When you throw your wallet out with $1000 let me know.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Moreover the Yetzer Hara to keep carrying would be stronger then.

Comment: I was under the impression that you can keep carrying, because only by putting it down are you violating Hotzaah.

Comment: @SethJ Many people's natural instinct upon discovering they are carrying is to suddenly stop. Also it isn't always practical to carry it to a makom petur or the original starting spot. So you are right, and I suppose it should be clarified, but I still think the takkana is well founded.

Comment: @SethJ So does hefsed merubah apply when its a choice between violating issur d'orisa and d'rabanan?

Comment: @double aa, right, but then you Davka _don't_ want to throw it out as Shmuel suggested - and it would not "certainly be Asur to continue to carry it" as Daniel stated (assuming you haven't stopped).

Comment: @mochinrechavim, I'm not sure what that has to do with it.

Comment: @DoubleAA, re "to a makom petur or the original starting spot", not to any _r'shus hayachid_?

Answer (score 1):

One might carry, forgetting that it is Shabbos, and also one might forget that the item in question is forbidden to carry on Shabbos.

Comment: If he forgets that it's Shabbos, he will be in big troubles anyways.

Comment: I don't mean the guy has a bout of amnesia and forgets what day it is. I mean he takes a can of soda outside to his friend without stopping to think maybe it's Shabbos, because it's such a simple, quick and easy action. That's not mis'asek, and it's very possible to happen, especially if he already has the thing in his pocket.

Comment: that makes more sense to be the reason for Muktza, as one *is* allowed to hold something in his hand on Friday afternoon.

Comment: I think that the chashash isn't for the first minute of shabbos - obviously it isn't, because right now you are remembering to check your clothes. The concern is rather that you might forget the thing in your pocket and what I described above will therefore happen 3 hours later. There is no concern that someone will forget something in his hand for 3 hours.

Comment: If the item is forgotten, carrying it is only a misasek.

Comment: In the cases I described the item is not forgotten at the time the carrying is being done.

Answer (score 0):

You have asked tosfos kashe. It is rather complicated so let me try to explain what exactly he forgot. If he forgot he had a needle but knew it was shabbos then it would be misasek. But tosfos answers he would remember he had the needle but would forget it was shabbos when it would be a 'shogeg'.

The meiri says that even if he forgot he had the needle and remembered it was shabbos when it is misasek in this case you would make a gezaira since if he would remember the needle it would be chayev misa and rovos case is different.
The pnai yeshuo explains this because rovo's case is a karmelis where one can never be chayav misa whereas our case is a 'street' where one can be.

The sfas emmes says that the example of the stone is different because no wants to carry a stone. Whereas here the tailor wants to carry the needle. This is a chiddush in the ptor of mleches machsheves. That it only applies when 'loi nicha lai'.

This is all taken from the mesivta gemoro where my present posts on daf yomi psochim, are all taken from.

Why one may go with t'fillin and we are not scared he will also forget it is shabbos and carry them, is a separate discussion.